# How to rebuild project after SWIG files changed?

Tags: python, c++, makefile, visual-studio-2015, swig

Given the below makefile:

```
TARGET = _example.pyd
OFILES = example.obj example_wrap.obj
HFILES =

CC = cl
CXX = cl
LINK = link
CPPFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -I. -Id:\virtual_envs\py351\include
CFLAGS = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -FS -Zc:strictStrings -O2 -MD -W3 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458
CXXFLAGS = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -FS -Zc:strictStrings -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577
LFLAGS = /LIBPATH:. /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:$(TARGET).manifest /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /INCREMENTAL:NO
LIBS = /LIBPATH:d:\virtual_envs\py351\libs python35.lib
.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C


{.}.cpp{}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -Fo @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.cc{}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -Fo @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.cxx{}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -Fo @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.C{}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -Fo @<<
    $<
<<

{.}.c{}.obj::
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -Fo @<<
    $<
<<

all: $(TARGET)

$(OFILES): $(HFILES)

$(TARGET): $(OFILES)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) /OUT:$(TARGET) @<<
      $(OFILES) $(LIBS)
<<
    mt -nologo -manifest $(TARGET).manifest -outputresource:$(TARGET);2

install: $(TARGET)
    @if not exist d:\virtual_envs\py351\Lib\site-packages mkdir d:\virtual_envs\py351\Lib\site-packages
    copy /y $(TARGET) d:\virtual_envs\py351\Lib\site-packages\$(TARGET)

clean:
    -del $(TARGET)
    -del *.obj
    -del *.exp
    -del *.lib
    -del $(TARGET).manifest

test:
    python runme.py
```

I'd like to improve a couple of things here:

- I'd like to consider swig files (*.i) in the makefile. For example, every time some swig file has been changed a new wrap file should be generated (ie: swig -python -c++ file_has_changed.cpp) and then rebuild the project
- I'd like to avoid having hardcoded object files. For instance, I'd like to use all cpp files using wildcards somehow

I've read a little bit of the docs talking about [Makefiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1tske6.aspx) but I'm still pretty much confused. How could I achieve this?

Right now I'm using a **hacky** solution like `swig -python -c++ whatever_file.i && nmake`, that's of course it's not ideal at all

REFERENCES

Achieving this inside visual studio IDE is quite easy following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969173/how-to-swig-in-vs2010/6117641#6117641) but I'd like to use this makefile inside SublimeText, that's why I'm quite interested on knowing how to have a proper Makefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Producing any kind of target from any kind of source, that's the essence of a makefile:

```
.i.cpp:
    swig -python -c++ $<
```

This elegance will, however, break with `nmake` ([as opposed to GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html)) if the `.cpp` file is missing because [`nmake` doesn't try to chain inference rules through a missing link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808674/nmake-inference-rules-limited-to-depth-of-1).
Moreover, it will break silently and "build" from stale versions of the files that are later in the build chain (which includes the resulting executable) if they are present.

Possible <s>kludges</s> workarounds here (save for ditching `nmake`, of course) are:

- invoke `nmake` multiple times, first, to generate all files that are an intermediate steps between two [inference rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/968fkazs.aspx) (which can in turn require multiple invocations if they are generated from one another), and then for the final targets

  - This requires an external script which can very well be another makefile. E.g.:
    move the current `Makefile` to `main_makefile` and create a new `Makefile` with commands for the main target like this:

    ```
    python -c "import os,os.path,subprocess;
               subprocess.check_call(['nmake', '/F', 'main_makefile']
                   +[os.path.splitext(f)[0]+'.cpp'
                     for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)
                                                 and f.endswith('.i')])"
    nmake /F main_makefile
    ```
- do not rely solely on inference rules but have an explicit rule for each `.cpp` to be produced (that's what CMake does btw)

  - this asks for the relevant part of Makefile to be autogenerated. That part can be `!INCLUDE`'d, but still, external code is needed to do the generation before `nmake` gets to work on the result. Example code (again, in Python):

    ```python
    import os,os.path,subprocess
    for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.i'):
        print '"%s": "%s"'%(os.path.splitext(f)[0]+'.cxx',f)
        #quotes are to allow for special characters,
        # see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/956d3677.aspx
        #command is not needed, it will be added from the inferred rule I gave
        # in the beginning, see http://www.darkblue.ch/programming/Namke.pdf, p.41 (567)
    ```

Comment: Your syntax is a batch rule: in it, a command would only be invoked once and fed all the sources. While mine will be invoked for each source separately ('cuz I dunno if `swig` can process multiple files in one invocation). See [Batch-Mode Rules - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2x0zs74.aspx) for an illustration.

Comment: @BPL I managed to concoct workarounds for `nmake`'s defect. They require to run it through external logic but, judging by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808674/nmake-inference-rules-limited-to-depth-of-1/5048633#5048633, it's exactly what its designers had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using CMake and this translates directly to using `autoconf` and `automake` and thereby makefiles.

The idea is to introduce the following variable

```
DEPENDENCIES = `swig -M -python -c++ -I. example.i | sed 's/\//g'`
```

and make your target depend on this. The above generates a list of dependencies of all headers and `.i` files your SWIG interface file may include.